Why is the Axiom of Choice Necessary in ZFC
Within the framework of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with the Axiom of Choice $(ZFC)$, when we considered the method of constructing the set of natural numbers, we regarded it as the smallest inductive set that satisfied the conditions that the empty set is a member of it and that if $ x $ belongs to it, then $x \cup \{x\}$ also belongs to it. From this definition, we arrived at the applicability of proof by induction on the propositions defined on it and derived the Peano axioms and properties of the set of natural numbers without needing to add any properties to this set as axioms. Here, the question that piqued my curiosity arises: Why did we add the Axiom of Choice to the ZF system to make all sets selectable (by this, I mean the existence of a choice function for these sets)? Isn't the selectability of a set due solely to the way it is constructed and does not need an axiom to impose whether it can or cannot be selected, even if we are unable to trace this construction or construct a proof of its selectability or non-selectability? For example, in the set of natural numbers, we concluded that it is selectable without needing this axiom, only from the way it was constructed.

How would you construct a choice function on $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)\setminus{\emptyset}$? Which element should be picked from $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$, for example?

The axiom of choice is literally what distinguishes ZFC from ZF (the "C" is right there in the name).

@Geoffrey: that doesn't really address the OP's question. The question can be phrased as: why isn't the axiom of choice just provable from ZF? AC in fact holds in the constructible universe $L$ so one needs to say something about this.

It turns out, for instance, that one needs the Axiom of Choice (in at least some form) to prove that non-measurable sets exist.  It turns out to be consistent with ZF that all sets are measurable.  It seems intuitive that the set reached via the usual construction (choose one member from each equivalence class of $([0, 1) / \Bbb Q$) ought to exist, but you need choice to prove it does.

@QiaochuYuan This is roughly what I wanted to ask, as I know about the independence of the Axiom of Choice from ZF axioms. What puzzles me is the set structure's inability to determine if it has a choice function without the Axiom of Choice. In simpler terms, saying a set has a choice function due to the Axiom of Choice is like saying parents can determine their child's physical traits, like eye and skin color, after birth.

@Bezina: this is not my field at all but it really sounds to me like you are trying to express an intuition about the constructible universe so it's perhaps worth reading about (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility).

Given surjective function $f: A \to B$, we can use AC to infer the existence of an injective function  $g: B \to A$.

Given any Dedekind infinite set $X$ (an alternative to AoI?), we can infer, without citing AC, the existence of $N\subset X$, $S: N\to N$, $x_0 \in N$ such that Peano's Axioms hold on $(N,~S,~x_0)$.
